# Recalculating price and reattaching currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

We have a price, say `5000,00 kr` per item and we have two items.
I calculate the new price to `10000` something like this:

```
var newPrice = parseInt(originalPrice) * parseInt(amount);
```

But I would like to keep the `,00` part and the currency in this case `kr`.

How would I go about to achieveme this the easiest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Comment: use `parseFloat` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `toFixed(2)`

```
var newPrice = (parseInt(originalPrice) * parseInt(ammount)).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to append the `,00` and the currency `kr` you can do

```
newPrice += ",00 kr"
```

But you probably don't want to add the `,00` if there already is a decimal part. So instead you should do this

```
newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2) + " kr"
```

This way `40` would be turned into `40.00 kr` and `19.9` would be `19.90 kr`.

And as @slash197 mentioned in the comments you'd have to parse the string using `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`. Otherwise the decimal part will be thrown away from the original string.